# Working out the difference in earnings

Tags: finance

I'm mathematically impaired/ignorant and trying to figure out the difference in earnings between my partner and I to work out a fair split of the bills.

So; I earn £2060 per month and partner earns £1650. As a percentage, how much more than her do I earn?

Therefore; If we had a mortgage payment of £850, by what percentage should we split the figure by so it’s proportionate to the difference in our earnings.

Any help sincerely appreciated,

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combined earnings are $2060+1650$.  So if you will split the rent in proportion to your earnings, you should pay
$$850\times \frac{2060}{2060+1650}$$
and your partner should pay
$$850\times \frac{1650}{2060+1650}.$$
The amounts are (to $2$ decimal places) $471.97$ and $378.03$ respectively.

As to your question about percentage, you earn 
$$\frac{2060-1650}{1650}\times 100\%,$$ that is, about $24.85\%$ more than your partner. I believe that this gives a less clear path to seeing what your rent contributions should be.

**Remark:** There is a good argument that the contributions should be proportional to after tax income rather than income. That argument may not please your partner.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the help.

Out of curiosity - Why do you think this gives a less clear path?

She wants everything to be '50/50' with money but I argue that's not fair on her as I earn more. I'm trying to find a way so that it's proportionately equal.

Interested in any thoughts people have.

Comment: In my experience, people have trouble with the concepts $x\%$ more than, $y\%$ less than. You should pay $24.85\%$ more than your partner. So the rent should be split in the ratio $124.85:100$. To find your contribution, it turns out that we should multiply $850$ by $\frac{124.85}{224.85}$. But my feeling is that this is less obvious than the argument I gave in the answer.

Comment: Is that latter example more so in the name of tidy maths and the former for ease of practical application?

Comment: I think a mathematician would be unlikely to use the percentage version of the argument. And I believe that for practical applications also, the approach in the answer (no percentages) is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

You earn more than her : (2060-1650)/1650 * 100% = 24.85 % ,

You should pay for the mortgage : 850*2060/(2060+1650)=850*2060/3710 = 471.96 ,

Your gf should pay the rest